# How to skip the user flow selecting screen when integrating Azure Active Directory B2C in spring-boot

Tags: spring-boot, azure-active-directory

I am trying to setup a springboot application and want to integrate Azure Active Directory B2C for user authentication and authorization. I followed the example as documented on https://github.com/microsoft/azure-spring-boot/tree/master/azure-spring-boot-starters/azure-active-directory-b2c-spring-boot-starter. The result is working, though as described in the example the user is presented with a user flow selection page before login.
I have no idea how to change the configuration so the user gets directed to the login page immediately. Any help would be appreciated.

regards.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The **azure-active-directory-b2c-spring-boot-starter** provides auto configurations to resolve the URLs. The resolver, **AADB2CAuthorizationRequestResolver**, tries to find registrationId in the url. If it can not find one, it will pass the request to next filter, i.e. OAuth2AuthorizationRequestRedirectFilter, which, in the end, redirect to the default failure handler, most likely **login?error** page.

You can configure your failure handler to take you to AD B2C login page using following code:

```
http.authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers("/api/v1") // Your Base URL
                .authenticated()
                .and()
                .apply(configurer).and()
                .oauth2Login()
                .failureUrl("/oauth2/authorization/B2C_1_test_user_flow") // Your Azure AD B2C login URL
```